# Regex substitution on filehandle not giving warning

Tags: regex, perl

Why is this not giving a warning (e.g. like "Regex substitution on a reference variable is illegal):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $fn = 'file.txt';
open ( my $fh, '>', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
print $fh "1,2,3,";
$fh =~ s/,$//;
print $fh "\n";
close $fh;
system "cat", $fn;
```

**Output**

```
1,2,3,
```

The same is true for any reference (not just GLOB references). Wouldn't it been better to print a warning in these cases, instead of silently ignoring the substitution operation?

Comment: [Part2 from next year](https://media.ccc.de/v/32c3-7130-the_perl_jam_2)

Comment: @GeorgMavridis: Those videos are amusing, but they don't address the original question at all.

Comment: It doesn't ignore the substitution. The reference is stringified, e.g. GLOB(0x123), then the substitution is applied that string, and if it succeeds the reference value is replaced with that modified string; otherwise the reference value is left unchanged. ps your /,$/ pattern doesn't match. A /GLOB/ pattern would

Comment: @DaveMitchell Ahh..wow! I wonder where this behavior could be useful

Comment: @DaveCross they address the issue not to expect perl to do whatever seems logical to me. Changing the regexp to something that matches (e.g) `s/O/O/` would simply destroy the filehandle.